# Windows Mobile - Using Timer control

Tags: windows-mobile, timer

I need to call web service from windows mobile at perticular interval. Is Timer  (System.Windows.Forms.Timer) the right control for this? Will this consume more battery power? Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your device is expected to be in power on state, while the timer is running, then you can use the Timer control. If however, there is no user action for some period of time, the device will sleep and the timer won't fire. In order to save battery life, it is a good decision to allow the device to go on sleep state.

Have a look at the [LargeIntervalTimer](http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/b2aa8648-0367-b457-db39-13dbb4d21623.htm) in OpenNetCF. This will wake the device from sleep state.

Comment: My application is going to listen to many events like SMS, Calls, Files, GPS, Contact, Calendar etc constantly. I cannot say when there is no user action. But, my application needs to listen every activity constantly. what do you suggest? I am currently using Timer control with interval of 60 mins. My appplication will listen to events constantly but I need to call server only once in 60 mins. So, my timer will be called once in 60 mins.

Comment: I recommend that you use LargeIntervalTimer. This ensures that the timer will fire, even if the application has gone in sleep state.

Comment: Yes, LargeIntervalTimer looks promising. I will try it and let you know.

Comment: LargeIntervalTimer is working even if the application has gone in sleep state. Thanks for great suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You P/Invoke the `CeSetUserNotificationEx` native function with the `dwType` field of the `CE_NOTIFICATION_TRIGGER` structure set to `CNT_TIME` and the `stStartTime` field set to the moment in the future when you want to call the web service.

Either launch an app each time and let it die after the call, or have an app always alive in the background waiting for a named event being set by the notification subsystem.